# Sorting in Asp.net Mvc using entityframework

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

```
 ViewBag.ParameterByName = string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortBy) ? "Name desc" : "";
 ViewBag.ParameterByCity = sortBy == "emp_City" ? "desc City" : "emp_City";
            var employees = db.Employees.AsQueryable();

switch (sortBy)
            {
                case "Name desc":
                    employees = employees.OrderByDescending(x => x.emp_name);
                    break;
                case "desc City":

                    employees = employees.OrderByDescending(x => x.emp_City);
                case "emp_City":
                    employees= employees.OrderBy(x => x.emp_City);


                default:
                    employees = employees.OrderBy(x => x.emp_name);
                    break;
        }
```

I am new to Asp.net Mvc.  I have  found an error in my switch statement that code is unreachable and also for 'employees'.  What should I do to fix that error?  It's not working for sorting employee name and also for Employee city.

Comment: Actually emp_City is my database column name.And it is same here it in the database.but why i got the switch and employees object as unreachable

Answer (score 1):

You are switching on sortby; are you sure these are the only possible conditions?  If you are sure on the possible values, maybe calling `sortby.ToLower()` to lower-case the evaluation of the conditions, just to be sure that isn't causing the error?  Also, 2 of the case statements are missing a break; at the end:

```
case "desc City":
    employees = employees.OrderByDescending(x => x.emp_City);
    break;
case "emp_City":
    employees= employees.OrderBy(x => x.emp_City);
    break;
```